# Angular 6: Service is undefined

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular for the first time and I'm trying to get a service running so I can get the contents of the file. I followed to heroes tutorial exactly where they explain how to do it and I did in the exact same way, but for some reason it doesn't work.

I get an error saying `ERROR TypeError: "this.fileService is undefined"`, and I'm not sure what the issue is.

`about.component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'
import { FileService } from './../file.service'

declare var require:any;
const markdown = require('markdown').markdown;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-about',
  templateUrl: './about.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./about.component.scss']
})
export class AboutComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private fileService:FileService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const aboutmeraw = this.fileService.readFile("./../assets/md/aboutme.md");
    this.aboutme = markdown.toHTML(aboutmeraw);
  }

  aboutme:string;

}
```

`file.service.ts`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FileService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  public readFile(file:string):Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(file);
  }
}
```

I know the method I return the HTTP file is wrong, but that's not the error I'm getting.

What's going on and how can I fix it?

Comment: how did you come to that conclusion? post the actual error

Comment: Might be that something is wrong with your import statement, referencing the service.ts file

Comment: @Sajeetharan That's pretty much the actual error. After that it just references a whole bunch of vendor.js and polyfill.js files. Nothing else.

Comment: @abdullahkady I wonder, I do have intellisense when I use it, so it should be right.  But I'll check it out.

Comment: @Stepepper is your reference directory correct ./../file.service .could you check the path?

Comment: @VaibhavKumarGoyal Yeah, it's the correct path. Just triple checked it.

Comment: Two things: 1) is `this.aboutme` defined somewhere and got the cut when pasting here?, and 2) did you import `HttpClientModule` to your module (`app.module.ts` if you are following the tutorials)?

Comment: Okay then can you check whether you have registered the service and httpmodule under the providers in app.module.ts? @Stepepper

Comment: Try setting the absolute path maybe? :D I actually see nothing wrong with your code at all, so I'm just sharing my thoughts

Comment: Is your service and component in the same module ?

Comment: @Jcl Christ, that was it. I looked over it completely. I forgot importing the HttpClientModule, and once I did import it the issue was fixed completely. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So for a while the error didn't make any sense, but I just looked over the documentation and forgot to import `HttpClientModule` in `app.module.ts`.

After adding it to that, it was fixed and it worked immediately.